# How to hide status icons completely on watch face

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I am creating a watch face. This watch face contains also battery, charging and connectivity indicators. Now I want the system icons to be hidden, so they don't interfere with watch face indicators when the device is charging or disconnected from the phone. How can I achieve this?
I checked the `WatchFaceStyle.Builder` class documentation and there seems to be only one related method: `setStatusBarGravity`. This method can only move indicators around the watch face, but they are still visible.
Is there any other way I'm missing? Or is it simply not possible at all?

Thanks for all your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

All watch faces are required to show the status icons so you cannot remove them entirely at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The status bar icons can be hidden using `setHideStatusBar(true)`.

This method appears to be currently undocumented and is perhaps only slated for release with Wear OS 2.3. As such, it may not be respected on older devices.